# Does Ubuntu come with disk partitioning in the installer?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows, disk

When I install ubuntu I want to know whether it will give me the option to partition my disk. I am installing ubuntu for my laptop and I need some of my windows stuff as well. I would be thankful to anyone who answers

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little more?  What exactly do you require for partitioning capabilities?  Ubuntu can automatically install itself alongside Windows, or you can manually adjust/create partitions.  All of these capabilities have been addressed in other question/answer pairs here, but I'm unsure which ones to best point you towards. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  It will allow you to manipulate your partitions.  Always be careful when dealing or using partitioning software.  When you get to the Installation type screen, that's where you can create/modify partitions

[image]

[image]

For more info you may look at [Manual disk partitioning guide for Ubuntu](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/)

Comment: What it will not give you is the ability to resize partitions that are mandatory for the system. E.g. you will not be able to resize the partition your kernel booted from. For that you will have to boot from another source (i.e. a Live-CD or live USB-stick)

Comment: @con-f-use Excellent point! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want a tool to modify partitions you can install GParted (it's partition manager).

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

But if you intend to use a partition manager in the system installation process you can choose this option while installing Ubuntu:

[image]

After that you will see it: (here is where you modify your partition)

[image]

If your having some doubts you can check the [Getting Started with Ubuntu - Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/) it's a beginner guide that will teach you every thing about Ubuntu, and it's update always when a new version of the operating system is released.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found `gparted` a lot more flexible than the partition tool during the installation. In another part of StackExchange I [already once described](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition/933#933) how to use gparted.

You could use a livecd (which has gparted installed by default) to shrink your Windows partition(s) and create partitions for your new Ubuntu installation. Then, when finished, start the installation program from the livecd. During the installation progress you'll only have to select your newly created partition(s).